# How to pass data outside router-oulet? Angular 4

Tags: angular, components

I have made two components, AppComponent and WelcomeComponent.

App component html have this structure:

```
<!-- header code divs and navs -->
<router-oulet> </router-oulet>
<app-welcome (valueChange)='displayCounter($event)'></app-welcome>
<!-- header code divs and navs -->
```

And the Welcome Component html have this one:

```
<div class="row center">
      <a (click)="loginFb()" id="download-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Registrarte</a>  
      </div>
```

So this is what I'm doing in Welcome Component:

```
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  error: any;
  autorized: boolean;

  @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter <boolean>;

  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.autorized = false;
  }

  loginFb() {
    console.log("holaa wey")
    this.valueChange.emit(this.autorized);
  }
```

AppComponent have this code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

    error: any;

  @Input() public autorized: boolean;

  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {
     this.autorized=true;
  }

  signOut(): void {
    this.af.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }

    displayCounter(count) {
      console.log("paso por sadsdf")
      console.log(count);
      this.autorized=count;
    }
```

So actually the output is:

```
"paso por sadsdf"
"holaa wey"
```

The only problem is that the html duplicates the WelcomeComponent like this:

imgur.com/a/wsdyyPt

How can I make this code works without selector `</app-welcome>` ?

`(valueChange)='displayCounter($event)`

Comment: what do you mean, without a selector?

Comment: You can't. No inputs and outputs on router outlet. Use a shared service.

Comment: No need for the "this.valueChange = new EventEmitter < boolean > ();" in the constructor. You already defined it outside and you emit the event in the 'loginFb' Function.

Comment: @ritaj how is the shared service done?